# React. Где хранить объект Chart.js

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

Пишу графики на React. Использую библиотеку `chart.js` (НЕ `react-chartjs-2`). У меня возникла потребность при старте приложения рендерить график, а после при клике изменять в нём данные и перерендерить его. Для того, чтобы это сделать, мне нужно где-то сохранить объект графика, а после при помощи этого объекта изменить в нём данные. Мне кажется, что `state` для этого плохо подходит. Подскажите пожалуйста, где же можно сохранить этот объект?

Comment: ```useState```? А чем он не подходит?

Comment: Просто React говорит, что состояние нужно использовать, когда нужно что-то отобразить. А тут двоякая ситуация

Answer (score 0):

Если объекты не будет меняться, просто вынесите их в константу

Например:

```
const chartUsersConfig = { 
   // some values
}

const chartFruitsConfig = {
  // some values
}
```

---

Либо же, например, создайте папку `helpers`, в ней файл `chart-config.js`
А в нём что-то типа:

```
const chartConfig = {
  user: {
    // some values
  },
  fruits: {
    // some values
  }
}

export { chartConfig }
```

А дальше подключаете где вам удобно:

```
// ...
<Chart data={userData} config={chartConfig.user} />
// ...
```

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос )

П.С. - код примерный, думаю данные сами прокините в нужные пропсы

Comment: Нет, вы не совсем меня поняли. Я имею ввиду, что мне нужно сохранить экземпляр класса Chart, который я получил в хуке useEffect, чтобы в после поменять в нём данные в обработчике клика.

Comment: @NaClnik тогда можете хранить его в ```state```, ничего плохого в этом нет. Всё зависит от того, как эти данные будут потом использоваться.  Гораздо проще дать толковый ответ, если покажете код